# Actionscript 3 Bind variables

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, binding

I am trying to set one bindable variable to be bound to another.  Essentially I want to create an alias.  I would give up, but this seems like something that would be good to know.

essentially, I want changes in model.configView to be reflected in view, so that things bound to view.... behave the same as things bound to model.configView... in this example

```
[Bindable]
var view = model.configView;
```

...
<mx:Label text="{view.lblThisLabel.name}" />

at the moment it does not, and I am getting errors that say "unable to bind to property 'lblThisLabel' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)"

Answer (score 1):

Not quite enough code here to really say what's going on, however you have made `view` bindable and that does not automatically mean that all of `view`'s children are bindable.  You'll have to go into `view` and make `lblThisLabel` bindable too.

Also it is hard for the rest of us to know how it works in your head.  Perhaps you should describe that too.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, I think that even if, with your actual code, `view` changes should be detected, `view` won't be updated if assigned `model.configView` property is not bindable as well...